# CakePHP - database sessions, ajax not saving

Tags: cakephp

I am using sessions saved in the database. Works well. Lot of data relating to pagination, browsing history etc is stored perfectly within the database.

However, I notice that data sent to a controller using Ajax is not being stored successfully.

If I debug the session within the controller called by ajax, right after I have set the session vars, I see the values appear to be stored correctly in the session, but on subsequent requests, it transpires that the session vars have NOT been saved.

I have done some testing and have found that the problem disappears if I change back to using "php" for the session instead of "database".

I have eliminated pretty much everything from the mix - and it boils down to Cake not saving session data that is sent by ajax. Again, simply switching back to using "php" for sessions, and everything works perfectly.

I wonder if anyone has experienced anything similar?

CakePHP 2.4

Many thanks.

Comment: Could you provide some code? Otherwise is hard to help

Comment: Reason I didn't provide any code is that this problem appears to be quite specifically related to the storing of sessions with database, as opposed to with php or cookie. Everything works fine when using "php" for saving session data, so I assume my code is all fine. The single action of switching to using database, causes some data to not be stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in case anyone is interested, it turns out that the issue I was having was not strictly related to storing sessions in the database.

My application was making 2 ajax calls at the same time, both attempting to update the session. This was a bug / error on my part, and was causing other session-related issues too, such as returning 403 error status.

I removed the offending bug and all is now well.